# Can I add a basic auth in only 1 resource in a API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2ei6.6.0 and I am trying to secure only one resource in my API file.

Can I secure only 1 resource without creating another API file?

```
<handlers>
     <handler class="org.wso2.rest.BasicAuthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

This option only work securing all the resources in an API file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the `BasicAuthHandler` implementation to perform the validation check only for that particular resource by introducing a filter. Or, you can convert the same logic which is in the handler to a class mediator and engage it to the respective API resource's `in-sequence` section.

With either of the mentioned approach, you will be able to achieve your requirement.